# 2 dataGrid on Form

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, grid

I posted two DataGrid on a form, but in the 2nd dataGrid binding does not work.
The properties ItemsSouse they show the same values. If one change in the second changes automatically.
How do I make it work properly?

```
<DataGrid Margin="8,72.04,8,-34" 
          Name="AskDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Вопросы}"
          SelectedCellsChanged="AskDataGrid_SelectedCellsChanged">

</DataGrid>

<DataGrid Margin="8,62,8,48.96"  
          Grid.Row="1" 
          Name="AnswersDataGrid" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ответы}"
          SelectionChanged="AnswersDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: You need to show your data context, ie the class that contains the fields you're binding to.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
<DataGrid Margin="8,62,8,48.96"  
      Grid.Row="1" 
      Name="AnswersDataGrid" 
      AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Ответы}"
      SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=AskDataGrid, Path=SelectedIndex}"
      SelectionChanged="AnswersDataGrid_SelectionChanged">
</DataGrid>
```

by the way... it isn't a good idea to use russian words in the code... (проще говоря - лучше на инглише писать всё - это типа хороший тон... да и людям тут понятнее будет ;-) )

Comment: I tried but nothing happened. but wnen i write AnswersDataGrid.ItemsSource =myDataSet.Tables["Answers"].DefaultView; in C# code this works.

Comment: hmmm... rather strange... I created two DataGrids and gave them same ItemSources - and SelectedIndex of second DataGrid was changin with selection in first DataGrid...